# Protecting AD object from being accidentally disabled?

Tags: windows, active-directory

If I set a "Deny" type permission to the "Everyone" well-known principal, in the "Write userAccountControl" property of an AD Object, like a User, it works kind of the same as the "Protect the object from accidental deletion", but protecting from accidental disabling, right? Is it viable in case of some VIP accounts or something like that, or it's a bad practice?

Comment: Well that would be a horrible idea, because "Everyone" includes... well, everyone... and denies always take precendence... so everyone would be denied the ability to modify that attribute, including Domain Admins, Account Operators, etc.

Comment: Can't hurt to try.

Comment: @RyanRies Thanks, but well, I don't think that would be a problem. Yes, even Domain Admins couldn't modify, but that property, as far I can see, is not modified very often, like "password never expires", "account disabled" etc, those things would be set up before and maybe once. What do you think? :)

Comment: Just be sure and document what you do so that the next administrator has a clue what he or she is walking into. :)  Also, beware of AdminSDHolder.  He's a cruel trickster.

Comment: ADminSDholder shouldn't affect user accounts

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a group other than "everyone" but presuming you have a working general "deny", if accounts are being "accidentally" disabled you should be able to track that person down who is disabling accounts to deliver re-reducation via the eventlog.  Other than inconvenience there is no harm in disabling an account but if you needed to in case of emergency (compromise), you'd now have to track down the right person to disable the account. How "bad" that practice is depends on your appetite for risk of being potentially unable to disable a compromised account readily.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, I was referring to disabling an account manually, from a script, etc., not it getting locked from bad password attempts or something.